# How to disable pydev code analysis and keep pylint code analysis

Tags: eclipse, pydev

In PyDev <= 5.6.0 I could disable the PyDev code analysis while still having PyLint do its work. I assume this was because PyLint was decoupled from the PyDev code analysis (it also had its own place in the PyDev->Editor Preferences).

Nowadays, PyLint seems to be integrated in PyDevs analysis. So, unfortunately, if I uncheck "Do code analysis?" there, I not only disable PyDev's, but also PyLint's code analysis, no matter if I choose "Use Pylint?" or not.

Is there any way to have PyLint running and PyDev's code analysis deactived at the same time in the current PyDev version?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a side-effect on the improvements done in PyDev 5.7.0.

Please report this at https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev as I think those settings should really be decoupled (i.e.: this is a bug and should be fixed).

So, now that we agree that they should be decoupled, I'm curious on why exactly would you like only the PyLint code analysis and not the PyDev one -- my rationale here is that the PyDev code analysis is much faster, works on unsaved files, usually has less false positives and in the current version the same report from PyDev or PyLint should be reported only once.

Comment: To my knowledge, PyLint has better configuration options. I am able to make it behave the way I like, whereas some seemingly non-configurable PyDev messages occasionally annoy me. Turning PyDev off was a nice and easy option until now. Thanks for your response, I'll go ahead and report this.